# Set notation of $S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

This is a simple question, but should this be written as:

$\hspace{120pt}S^1 \times S^1 = \{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}:|z_1|=|z_2|=1\}$

Comment: And... what is exactly the question?

Comment: Whether or not I have written $S^1 \times S^1$ correctly in set notation.

Comment: You have written it correctly.

Comment: That is certainly one way of writing it.

Comment: @Seth Is there a better way of writing it?

Comment: You might also write $S^1\times S^1 = \{(z_1, z_2)\mid z_1\in S^1, z_2\in S^1\}$, which is evidently correct because it is a direct application of the definition of $\times$.

Comment: I wouldn't say there is a "better" way.  Just different ways.

Comment: Alright. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This set is the set of ordered pairs of points in a circle. There are many ways of wirting it. The 'best' one is that one that fits for the concrete problem that needs it.